# Not able to create new directory with variable (PHP)

Tags: php, mkdir

Hello I'm trying to create a directory in the users/ folder. When the user registers a vpb_save_details.php is being opened. And mkdir is ran to create a user  with the username as directory name.

The user is being registered as normal but the problem that no directory is created, not even the /user directory.

If i run this code:

```
   <?php
   mkdir("blah", 0777);
   ?>
```

The directory bla is created, but if I run my code vpb_save_details.php, nothing happens.

This is a part of the code:

```
//If the user is validated and every thing is alright, then save the user details and display success message to the user 
            //otherwise, display error message to the user
            if ($vpb_error == '')
            {
                //Encrypt user information with Base64 before saving them to a file
                if(fwrite($vpb_database, "\r\n".base64_encode($fullname)."::::::::::".base64_encode($username)."::::::::::".base64_encode($email)."::::::::::".base64_encode($encrypted_user_password).""))
                {
                    echo '<font style="font-size:0px;">completed</font>';
                    echo '<div class="info">Congrats <b>'.$fullname.'</b>, you have registered successful. <br>You may now click on the login button to log into your account.<br>Thanks.</div>';
                      //
                      // HERE! I create a folder in the users directory with the variable $username as username
                      //
                      $newUserName = $username;
                      $userPath = "users/".$newUserName;
                      mkdir("$userPath", 0777);
                      //copy("index.php",$userPath/index.php);

                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<div class="info">Sorry, your account creation was unsuccessful, please try again (1).</div>';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo $vpb_error;
            }
            fclose($vpb_database);
```

I have absolutely no idea what the problem could be? the code:

```
                  $newUserName = $username;
                  $userPath = "users/".$newUserName;
                  mkdir("$userPath", 0777);
```

Should work just fine, or am I missing a small detail?

Comment: Does the users folder exist? if not change your `mkdir` to `mkdir("$userPath", 0777, true);`. If it does exist check the permissions on the users dir to make sure it's writable

Comment: are you sure the if statement is returning true?

Comment: @chislonden That did the trick, I thought the users directory would be created by mkdir...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes.

```
mkdir($userPath, 0777);
```

Comment: The quotes won't have any affect.  They're unnecessary but I can't see how they are causing the problem

Comment: Quotes will treat the variable as string.

Comment: Your 'if' condition is failing then, but remember the quotes shouldn't be there .

Comment: If the quotes are present , a directory called $userPath would be created rather than a directory with the name present in the variable $userPath.